# How to get start and end dates of current month

Tags: sql, database, h2

How to get start date and end dates in a query from database.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/06/sql-first-and-last-day-of-month.html

Only thing that isn't covered is how to retrieve the current date... see rexem's post.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Article explained what I needed to understand the logic behind for getting the desired date. Substract no. of days from current date.

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable on this site. Please endure you answer is stand-alone with links for reference only.

Answer (score 1):

[CURRENT_DATE[()] | CURDATE() | SYSDATE | TODAY](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#current_date) = returns current date

Start of month:

```
DATE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) +'-'+ EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) +'-01'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to get date from system rathor than a table.

Comment: I tried select DATEADD('MONTH', 1, SYSDATE)
its giving me 2009-10-08 23:15:16.578...
but I need first date (2009-10-01 00:00:00.000)of the current month
Thanks!

Comment: I'm going on record: H2 SQL is limited

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, start of month:

```
DATE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) +'-'+ EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) +'-01'
```

End of month:

```
DATEADD('DAY', -1, DATEADD('MONTH', 1, DATE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) +'-'+ EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) +'-01'))
```