# How to make a SQL looping for date?

Tags: sql-server

```
select CAST(convert(varchar, a.rechargedate, 112) as datetime)as RechargeDate,
COUNT(distinct a.mobileno) AS UnitTotal,
SUM(a.amount) AS AmountTotal
from recharge a
where *a.rechargedate BETWEEN '2009-07-01' AND '2009-07-31'*
group by CAST(convert(varchar, a.rechargedate, 112) as datetime)
order by a.rechargedate
```

above is my sql query. in the
 `(((( a.rechargedate BETWEEN '2009-07-01' AND '2009-07-31'  )))))`
i would change it by using looping. so if next time i wanna change date to august. it will automatically loops by itself. i no need to manually key in the date to 2009-08-01........
got anyone can help me ? show me how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is just a query that you are using for yourself to veiw data, or if it is suppose to be in a sproc.  If it is just a utility query, you could do something like this.,

```
declare @firstofmonth as smalldatetime
declare @endofmonth as smalldatetime

--Set the inital month to loop
set @firstofmonth = '01/01/2009'
set @endofmonth = '01/31/2009'

WHILE @firstofmonth >= '09/01/2009' --This would be the condition to end the loop

Begin

select CAST(convert(varchar, a.rechargedate, 112) as datetime)as RechargeDate,
    COUNT(distinct a.mobileno) AS UnitTotal,
    SUM(a.amount) AS AmountTotal
From recharge a
Where a.rechargedate BETWEEN @firstofmonth AND @endofmonth
group by CAST(convert(varchar, a.rechargedate, 112) as datetime)
order by a.rechargedate

SET @firstofmonth = DateAdd(m,1,@firstofmonth)
SET @endofmonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@firstofmonth())+1,0))

End
```

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on your logic, here are some options:

1. take @startDate and @endDate as parameters for the sproc
2. if you can logically tie those dates to current date, you can [calculate them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397291/how-to-get-start-and-end-dates-of-current-month/1397401#1397401) in the sproc (or function) based on getdate() (will give you current date)