# Looping in SQL Server using Date

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a question to you,

I need a script related to my project, it should be like,

Table `Table_Day` contains all the dates for 2016 (i.e., 20160101, 20160102, ...)

For each day, I have to insert 6 personal_id's.

Like this

```
'date_id' 'personal_id'
“20160101” “1001”,“20160101” “1002”,“20160101” “1003”,“20160101” “1004”,“20160101” “1005”,“20160101” “1006”--for example

“20160102” “1001”
“20160102” “1002”
“20160102” “1003”
“20160102” “1004”
“20160102” “1005”
“20160102” “1006”
```

I want to insert these data till the end of 2016 (date reference from `Table_day`).

Comment: Thank you for telling us your requirements. Now what is stopping you implementing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the below query to loop dates and get your homework done :

```
        declare @firstofmonth as smalldatetime
        declare @endofmonth as smalldatetime

        --Set the inital month to loop
        set @firstofmonth = '01/01/2016'
        set @endofmonth = '12/31/2016'

        WHILE @firstofmonth >= '01/01/2016' --This would be the condition to end the loop

        Begin
---Check  here if dates exist in dates table and do insert


         Insert into Table_Day (blah blah black sheep)

         --Increment Date
        SET @firstofmonth = DateAdd(m,1,@firstofmonth)
        SET @endofmonth = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@firstofmonth())+1,0))

        End
```

This was the first stack overflow result that came when I searched [looping dates in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524033/how-to-make-a-sql-looping-for-date)

The above is just a way you may use the looping to get your specific dates and then do insert.