# Getting the previous months data

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

This seems to have been answered several times for the past 30 days. But seemingly not what I need.

If, for example, today is July 10th, 2012. I'm looking to pull all of June's data. I will need to run this query several days after the start of each month

Comment: A lot of dateadd(mm, -1, getdate()) type stuff. However I believe this keeps the day the same. for the example eabove would yeild june 10th, 2012

Comment: You _need_ to specify the RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL...) you are using; they all have different date functions.

Comment: Are you looking for a date range like this?

'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( DateStart = '9/4/2010' AND TimeStart >= '20:00' )'

Comment: You may want to look up the OLAP functions such as LAG.

Comment: i'm looking for the range of the previous month. but it will be a script that runs every month

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get start and end dates of current month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397291/how-to-get-start-and-end-dates-of-current-month)  See the tutorial linked in the top answer. It is basically the same question, except you want the previous month not the current month, so just subtract a month from the current date and use the same logic.

Answer (score 3):

There is certainly better ways to do this, but one way would be this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = '20120710'

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourDateColumn >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@Date),112)+'01' 
AND YourDateColumn < CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@Date,112)+'01')
```

Answer (score 0):

-- first day of previous month

```
select DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate())-1,0)
```

-- last day of previous month

```
Select DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month, 
                                            DateDiff(Month, 0,GETDATE())-1,0)))
```

Please replace GETDATE() with your date column

Answer (score -1):

Ah, in that case you need something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  reporting_table_name_goes_here
WHERE
  DATEPART(month, YourDateColumn) = DATEPART(month, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))
AND DATEPART(year, YourDateColumn) = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()))
```

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: I assume that the OP would like to have data from the correct year as well: this query will return all data for the month of June, for all years.

Comment: This isn't right. For one part, if there is an index on `DateCreated`, then this way you won't be able to use it. Also, this will return any records for one month disregarding the year.

Comment: @Pondlife Fair enough, I'll make it more correct even if it is sub-optimal.

Comment: @jonnyGold - Adding the year is not sub-optimal. The fact that you are using a function on the column is the suboptimal part, the year part is just making sure that the query returns what was asked